# Why is quayside pronounced as "keyside" or kēsīd?

Tags: pronunciation

I was listening to the song of Dire Straits, *Down To The Waterline*.
It says:

> Sweet surrender on the quayside.

Before I saw the lyrics I heard it even as "queenside", then I realized it said "keyside" (I know it isn't a word but it heard like that) and then when I found the lyrics I saw the word ***quayside***.

Which rule is applied in the pronunciation of this word?

Comment: "Quay" is a word in its own right and the pronunciation for "quayside" follows that pattern. You should be able to use a standard dictionary to see the correct pronunciation.

Comment: Then why is *quay* pronounced that way?

Comment: Because English gets words from many different language sources and our spelling and pronunciation are never consistent.

Comment: Oh so in this case there isn't neither a rule?

Comment: Not really. Quay is an odd word and, honestly, often gets pronounced incorrectly even by native speakers... I'll bet your dictionary lists both "key" and "qway" as options for pronunciation. Wikipedia does.

Comment: **Quay** is a French word that entered English during the Middle English period. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED24110&egs=all&egdisplay=open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Quayside* is pronounced as *quay* and *side* combined. This corresponds to the pronunciation of *keyside* since *quay* has the same pronunciation as *key*.

Generally, you can predict the pronunciation of an English word you've never heard before because some parts may appear familiar, i.e., you may recognize its parts in other words, and then, based on their position, word's assumed language of origin, and other information, *guess* its pronunciation.

This method isn't reliable because English took many words from different languages without adjusting their spelling to conform to the rules of English spelling – not to mention words changed their spelling over time – so you'd have to know a lot about a word before attempting to guess its correct pronunciation.

With that in mind, the only way to learn the pronunciation of new words is to consult a dictionary with a supplementary pronunciation guide / sample.

Comment: When many of these words were taken into the language, the spelling rules had not yet been normalized. There were usually several, or even many, ways to spell the same word.